# Receiving loads of sms with a consumer level android device

Tags: android, sms

I need to create an Android application which reads incoming SMS message immediately, parses it and deletes it.

This is for an SMS promotion system but I am not sure if this can handle high loads of messages easily.

Trying to do this to see if it works is not feasible; that's why I am asking this question: Can this system work or is it a must to have multiples of special devices (special = I don't know what they are) to do this kind of work?

Comment: Consumer level devices are limited to around 1 SMS per second. You will have issues with your mobile operator also regarding queued delivery for example. How much traffic do you define as "high load"?

Comment: Thanks for this important information. 1 to 10 SMS per second in busy times or there may be seconds with no SMSes too. If I can't do this, should I make deals with the mobile operator, what is the way to go?

Comment: If you expecting a high volume of messages then it really does make sense to look around for an SMS aggregator (there are plenty around depending on your needs and budget). Not necessarily a mobile operator as they tend to be more expensive and tricky to make deals with. On a side note, by storing SMS's on your SIM card so often  you are going to end up killing your SIM card with so many read/writes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with small knowledge of few concepts like

1) `BroadCast Listeners:`

This would be useful for capturing the Incoming messages before reaching to the INBOX this can be achieved by setting the Priority to 1000.`(sometimes the Inbox takes more priority so reliability is 90%)`

2)A `class` which is used to seperate you expected message alone and releasing the other messages to inbox. Its not too complex if you look into the tutorials online for capturing incoming messages.

3)Then you need to `send the response` to the desired number you want to do. look this tutorial for example http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-sms-message-in-android/

I have done all these in two days time with small knowledge gained through tutorials online

Sure you can get more help. the only thing you need to do is break your tasks into modules and look solutions seperately.

All the best,

Comment: Thank you @sam, what was the number of users sending messages; could the device respond quickly enough for lots of SMSes?

Comment: It is upon the logic you wrote to handle on the message.. for me i just need to track the SMS from a particular number and I am receiving and sending message without any interference.. about 10 to 15 messages receiving and sending.

Comment: As I am looking for the feasibility of the solution for messages coming from various numbers in huge quantity, I will wait a little more to see if any others comment on the feasibility, then, I will mark your answer as accepted. Thank you for sharing your experience.